# Skrollr.js not allowing users to scroll on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, fullscreen, parallax

I'm using skrollr.js for parallax effect on desktop. However when you look on an iphone you are unable to scroll down the page at all. I only had this issue occur after I installed skrollr.js. I'm using Bootstap as a css framework. This is what I have for the first section of the site (the home screen). Thanks so much for your help. I'm kind of new at using js plugins.

```
<!-- Full Page Image Header Area -->
<div class="header" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-500="background-position:0px -250px;">
  <div class="vert-text" data-0="opacity: 1" data-350="opacity: 0">
    <div class="container">
      <img class="logo-icon-header" src="img/logo-icon-color.png">
      <h1>Go with Missions.me and change<br>lives around the world</h1>
      <hr class="thick-hr">
      <p class="header-start">Start</p>
      <span class="header-start-icon"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Full Page Image Header Area -->
```

and the css

```
.header {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: url(../img/home-video-placeholder.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Im having the same issue but did a quick google and found [this](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/265). I think that will solve the problem: